# Sitecore Media Library MaxSize

Tags: image, sitecore, media, validation

In Sitecore, I'd like to set Upload MaxSize only for image files.
We can update Media.MaxSizeInDatabase to set the MaxSize, but this setting includes all files in Media Library.

Is there any way to set MaxSize only for image files? Or, can I create any validation for this??

Thank you in advance!!

========= Update ==========

I tried to use all code and setting, but it was not working. I think Code is fine, but I might have to make sure the place of configurations. When I add "xmlns:patch" attribute in  on the top, like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
```

It show error "Unrecongnized attribute xmlns:patch". So, I added the configurations in "/configuration/sitecore" element in a web.config, like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    .....
    <sitecore database="SqlServer">
        <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
            <sitecore>
                <processors>
                    <uiUpload>
                        <processor mode="on" type="ImageMaxSize.ImageItemValidator2, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize, Sitecore.Kernel']">
                            <restrictedExtensions hint="raw:AddRestrictedExtension">
                                <!-- Be sure to prefix with a dot -->
                                <extension>.jpg</extension>
                                <extension>.jepg</extension>
                                <extension>.png</extension>
                                <extension>.bmp</extension>
                            </restrictedExtensions>
                        </processor>
                    </uiUpload>
                </processors>
            </sitecore>
        </configuration>
```

This is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch in your own processor into `uiUpload` to check the file size for certain types, in a very similar way to this post from Mike Reynolds to [restrict certain file types to be upload](http://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/10/04/restrict-certain-types-of-files-from-being-uploaded-in-sitecore/).

```
public class ImageCheckSize : UploadProcessor
{       
    public List<string> RestrictedExtensions { get; set; }

    public ImageCheckSize()
    {
        RestrictedExtensions = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Process(UploadArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
        if (args.Destination == UploadDestination.File)
            return;

        foreach (string index in args.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = args.Files[index];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName) && IsRestrictedExtension(file.FileName))
            {
                if ((long) file.ContentLength > MaxImageSizeInDatabase)
                {
                    args.ErrorText = string.Format("The image \"{0}\" is too big to be uploaded. The maximum size for uploading images is {1}.", file.FileName, MainUtil.FormatSize(MaxImageSizeInDatabase));
                    Log.Warn(args.ErrorText, this);
                    args.AbortPipeline();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsRestrictedExtension(string filename)
    {
        return RestrictedExtensions.Exists(restrictedExtension => string.Equals(restrictedExtension, Path.GetExtension(filename), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }

    public static long MaxImageSizeInDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetLongSetting("Media.MaxImageSizeInDatabase", 524288000L);
        }
    }
}
```

And then add in the required config changes. Create a new config file in `/App_Config/Includes` (e.g. ImageSizeCheck.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">

  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <uiUpload>
        <processor mode="on" type="Custom.Business.Pipeline.Upload.ImageCheckSize, Custom.Business"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize, Sitecore.Kernel']">
          <restrictedExtensions hint="list">
            <extension>.jpg</extension>
            <extension>.png</extension>
          </restrictedExtensions>
        </processor>
      </uiUpload>
    </processors>

    <settings>
      <setting name="Media.MaxImageSizeInDatabase" value="1MB" />
    </settings>

  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You will also need to add another processor into `attachFile` processors to handle if the user attaches a new file to an existing media item - use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to see the implementation in `Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.CheckSize,Sitecore.Kernel`.

One caveat to this is that the displayed error message is not too friendly, but the error is logged correctly in the log files :(

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated more info. I don't know why it is not working. Could you make sure if the place of configuration in web.config file is correct??

Comment: You need to add the config in a new file to patch it with the xmlns:patch namespace. I updated the answer, but take a look at the [Sitecore File Patching document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/include_file_patching_facilities_sc6orlater-a4.pdf). Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. But, it doesn't check the "Media.MaxImageSizeInDatabase" value (1MB). I added extensions (.jpg, .png) in setting. And if I try to upload which is less than 1MB, it shows the same error. It seems like it only check restrictedExtensions in processor.

Comment: Use dotPeek to inspect the code of `Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.CheckSize` in `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`. You want to merge the logic there with the same check as here and then add a processor in `processors/attachFile/processor` into the config (essentially the same as above). If you get stuck let me know and I'll update the code tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just I wonder if I have to add it because I tested it (overwrite the same item), but no issue. It worked. Please let me get your updated code for this. Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Added the config ([http://pastebin.com/7cYV0G63](http://pastebin.com/7cYV0G63)) and code ([http://pastebin.com/rUSeq1r6](http://pastebin.com/rUSeq1r6)) to Pastebin. Again, the error messages are not too friendly, not sure why it doesn't work Sitecore calls the same thing... but it does the job...

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I don't want where your skills are from. Awesome!! I added Alert issue and you commented :)