# Sitecore 'getMediaStream' is not working

Tags: compression, sitecore, pipeline

now I'm using Dianoga (https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga) for image compression.
This tool is for png and jpg/jpeg files and PNG file is working fine. But, if I upload JPG file, the upload tool box is freezing like screenshot. 

[image]

This is the execution line.

```
var jpegtran = Process.Start(ToolPath, " -optimize -copy none -progressive -outfile \"{0}\" \"{0}\"".FormatWith(tempFilePath));
```

If I change the code like,

```
var jpegtran = Process.Start(ToolPath, " -optimize -copy none -progressive -outfile \"{1}\" \"{0}\"".FormatWith(tempFilePath));
```

JPG file updated, but no compression process. The log says,

**"ERROR Could not run the 'getMediaStream' pipeline for '/sitecore/media library/Images/satellite-westtibet'. Original media data will be used"**

This is my web.config file in /App_Config/Include/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
        <sitecore>
            <processors>
                <attachFile argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.AttachArgs">
                    <processor mode="on" type="Validations.Attach.ImageAttachMaxSize, Custom.Validations" patch:before="processor [@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Attach.CheckSize,Sitecore.Kernel']">
                        <restrictedExtensions hint="list">
                            <extension>.jpg</extension>
                            <extension>.jepg</extension>
                            <extension>.png</extension>
                            <extension>.bmp</extension>
                        </restrictedExtensions>
                    </processor>
                </attachFile>
                <uiUpload>
                    <processor mode="on" type="Validations.Upload.ImageUploadMaxSize, Custom.Validations" patch:before="processor [@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize, Sitecore.Kernel']">
                        <restrictedExtensions hint="list">
                            <extension>.jpg</extension>
                            <extension>.jepg</extension>
                            <extension>.png</extension>
                            <extension>.bmp</extension>
                    </restrictedExtensions>
                </processor>
            </uiUpload>
        </processors>

        <pipelines>
            <getMediaStream>
                <processor type="Validations.Compression.ImageCompression, Custom.Validations" />
            </getMediaStream>
        </pipelines>
        <settings>
            <setting name="Media.MaxImageSizeInDatabase" value="600KB" />    
            <setting name="Media.Resizing.Quality" value="72" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Error with empty values of Width and Height**
[image]

Comment: The first execution line was correct. Did you copy the `Dianoga Tools` folder to the root directory of your site? I presume you added the code to your own project (as opposed to using the one from Github). Add in the DLL into the processor also, e.g. `<processor type="Validations.Compression.ImageCompression, MyDLL.Name" />`

Comment: Hi @jammykam again, I copied **Dianoga Tools** directory. That's why PNG compression is working. As you mentioned, I have added my dll file (Custom.Validations) in bin folder, **but it is not working**, same freezing. You might know  what I want to implement. I'd like to combine the upload restriction with image compression. So, I added Dianoga sources into upload restriction process. Total only one project. This is the **JpegOptimizer.cs** source from Dianoga,  http://codepad.org/krYda4yA

Comment: The 2 work independently, since the Dianoga works on the `getMediaStream` pipeline it works independently of the upload process (i.e. when the media is served). Do the image actually upload successfully? If so, does the optimizer work when you view images from the front end?

Comment: Yes, after the freezing, I refresh the page and go to media library , I can see the uploaded the file, but no Width and Height value. Updated the screenshot. So, if I call the image which has no values of width and height in RichText Area, calling image is not working. Empty spaces are added in the image area.

Comment: @jammykam Do you think this process is not a right way to implement? If this is really complicated issue, do you have any suggestion to use both restriction and compression??

Comment: I just tried adding in [Dianoga as NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dianoga/) into the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27956033/661447) and it all works fine (no other changes): http://imgur.com/BYt1aNT http://imgur.com/YGh3YUf Personally I would use NuGet... or use the code as-is, don't make any changes yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much @jammykam, I will try and let you know how it is going. Really appreciate that.

Comment: @jammykam do you know why I got missing "FlashUpload" and "Media" namespace in "Sitecore.Shell.Applications"?? I'm using 7.0v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68889/discussion-between-jammykam-and-jay).

Comment: Kamruz, Fixed. Thank you for your help!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue. The problem was that I had to "**unblock**" the jpegtran.exe file. That's it.

[image]

Comment: Doh! Probably why I didn't have an issue using NuGet since it didn't present the same issue. Glad it's fixed!